# Count the number of a particular kind of files from console

Tags: linux, shell

I want to count the number of some `xyz` files from console.

I have an arrange like this:

**Folder-A**

**Folder-B**

**Folder-C**

All of them have `xyz` files inside.

I need the command *to return the number of `xyz` files* and the location of it.

**For example**: /home/path/to/A 25; then for B and so on.

Could it be possible? I thought in using `find -name *.xyz`, but do not know what to use next.

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for i in FolderA FolderB FolderC
do
    echo -n $i :
    find $i -type -f -name '*.yzx' | wc -l
done
```

That should do the trick.

`echo -n` prints a line without the line return, so it should print something like:

```
Folder A: 17
Folder B: 0
Folder B: 4
```

Comment: @HernanMiraola It's longer because it prints a line for each folder, not a single "total" line.

Comment: ooh, good. That's what i was needing. Thanks. I will try it now

Comment: echo -n is for printing the Folder name: <count> in the same line avoiding a newline after ':'

Comment: Is it possible to put something like a "*" to search in all folders?

Comment: If you want to display no of '.xyz' files in each directory in your system then you need to have a few things -
1. Can search inside '/' root path
2. cd /; DIR_LIST="`ls -d /*`"
3. @blue112's solution above use $DIR_LIST as argument to for loop instead of 'FolderA FolderB FolderC'.
That will find and display number of *.xyz files in each directory in your system. Hopefully (if you have read only permissions to all of them).
Good Luck!

Answer (score 1):

```
find FolderA FolderB FolderC -type f -name '*.xyz' | wc -l
```

- . where start search (. - from current directory)
- Use -type f to include only files (not links or directories).
- `wc -l` means "word count, lines only." Since find will list one file per line, this returns the number of files it found.

Comment: wow..beautiful solution. Thank you! I will try and accept if it works.

Comment: But what you write searchs in folder A, B and C?

Comment: i've edited. instead of current directory start search from that folder.

Comment: is it possible to put something like a "*" when the number of folders is too big?

Comment: nope, if your target folders are in same folder. do find their parent directory. like, if all folder(a,b,c,d, ...) are inside FOLDER directory, do find in FOLDER

Answer (score 0):

Adapting the solution by @tso:

```
for d in Folder-A Folder-B Folder-C
do
  find $d -type f -name '*.xyz'
done | wc -l
```

Getting separate counts for each folder:

```
for d in Folder-A Folder-B Folder-C
do
  echo $d $(find $d -type f -name '*.xyz' | wc -l)
done
```

Comment: Ah, no, he wants to have separate counts for each directory. I will update my post.